# Converting dynamic row into column in linq

Tags: linq

[image]

```
  var Getitems = (from u in db.EmailSettings
                        join s in db.SecurityRoles on u.SecurityRoleID equals s.SecurityRoleID
                        group u by new { u.SecurityRoleID,s.SecurityRoleName} into g
                        select new
                        {
                            TransTypeId = (from v in db.EmailSettings
                                           //join s in db.SecurityRoles on v.SecurityRoleID equals s.SecurityRoleID
                                           where v.SecurityRoleID == g.Key.SecurityRoleID

                                           select new
                                           {
                                               //username = s.SecurityRoleName,
                                               trans = v.TransTypeID
                                           }),
                                    SecurityRoleName=g.Key.SecurityRoleName,
                                    SecurityRoleId=g.Key.SecurityRoleID,


                        }).ToList();
```

For example in    TransTypeId  i  have 3 rows of data .. i want to convert tat to single row like SecurityRoleName ,SecurityRoleId,Row1,row2,row3..
where TransTypeId  can have any no of rows .. do any one help me to get the desired result

i want the result as the above screen

Comment: It's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve. What will be the **type** of the element of the resulting list?

Comment: mate you want to take data from 2 tables `EmailSettings` and `TransTypeId`, in order to obtain a `complex object`. So, post the 2 tables model and the model class for the complex object. Then we can figure out a way to help you.

Comment: i took that in a new object...  and assigned to a list thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Getitems = (from u in db.EmailSettings
                    join s in db.SecurityRoles on u.SecurityRoleID equals s.SecurityRoleID
                    group u by new { u.SecurityRoleID,s.SecurityRoleName} into g
                    select new
                    {
                        TransTypeId = (from v in db.EmailSettings
                                       //join s in db.SecurityRoles on v.SecurityRoleID equals s.SecurityRoleID
                                       where v.SecurityRoleID == g.Key.SecurityRoleID

                                       select new
                                       {
                                           //username = s.SecurityRoleName,
                                           trans = v.TransTypeID
                                       }),
                                SecurityRoleName=g.Key.SecurityRoleName,
                                SecurityRoleId=g.Key.SecurityRoleID,


                    }).ToList();
```

After that you can get the above result by creating a new list in every for each loop by using  transactiontypenames = new List() like below code

```
List<transactiontypename> transactiontypenames;
        transactiontypename transactiontypenameobj;
        foreach (var x in Getitems)
        {
           transactiontypenames = new List<transactiontypename>();
                objsecurityVM = new SecurityRoleVM();
                objsecurityVM.User = x.SecurityRoleName;
                objsecurityVM.SecurityRoleId = x.SecurityRoleId;

                foreach (var y in x.TransTypeId)
                {
                    transactiontypenameobj = new transactiontypename();
                    transactiontypenameobj.Transtypes = y.trans;
                    transactiontypenames.Add(transactiontypenameobj);
                }
                objsecurityVM.TransTypes = transactiontypenames;

                objlistsecurityroleVM.Add(objsecurityVM);

          }

        objEmailSetting.TableData = objlistsecurityroleVM;
        return View(objEmailSetting);
```

Hope it will be useful for you